# Combine multiple CSV into one single CSV column wise

Tags: shell, csv

I have many csv files with column 1 with the same information but column 2 is different.

For ex.
CSV1 has the following information

```
AAA, 11
BBB, 22
CCC, 33
```

And CSV2 has the following

```
AAA, 1111
BBB, 2222
CCC, 3333
```

I tried to CAT the files and I end up getting a file concatenated by Rows. But I am looking for something like the following output in a new csv. I am looking for a way to do it in shell.

Result.csv should be

```
AAA, 11, 1111
BBB, 22, 2222
CCC, 33, 3333
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [`join`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/join):

First file:

```
$ cat 1
AAA, 11
BBB, 22
CCC, 33
```

Second file:

```
$ cat 2
AAA, 1111
BBB, 2222
CCC, 3333
```

Join them:

```
$ join -t, 1 2
AAA, 11, 1111
BBB, 22, 2222
CCC, 33, 3333
```

Comment: Thanks, but i have 20 + files in the same format. Do you think this is the ideal solution. Any other way of doing it?

Comment: Then please provide an example of your real usecase.

Answer (score 0):

try this one-liner:

```
 awk -F, -v OFS="," '{a[$1]=a[$1]?a[$1]FS$2:$2}END{for(x in a)print x,a[x]}' file1 2 3 ....
```

Comment: cd $testFolder/Results
echo > Results.csv
cd ..
for f in $(find . -name "sample.csv")
do
 echo $f
 cat $f >> Results.csv 
done            # So now, instead of cat i want to use awk given at the top. But I dont want to manually provide the file as input. It should find each sample.csv file and keep appending to Results.csv as mentioned in my question. Is there a way to do this?